# Haproxy acl rules is not working

Tags: acl, haproxy, http2

I trying to configure haproxy-1.7.3 with HTTP2 support next acl rules:

```
acl rule0 hdr_beg(host) -i i0.
acl rule02 ssl_fc_alpn -i h2 and hdr_beg(host) -i i0.
use_backend i02 if rule02
use_backend i0 if rule0

acl rule1 hdr_beg(host) -i i1.
acl rule12 ssl_fc_alpn -i h2 and hdr_beg(host) -i i1.
use_backend i12 if rule12
use_backend i1 if rule1

backend i0
    server node1 192.168.40.51:5000 ssl verify none

backend i02
    mode tcp
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    server node1 192.168.40.51:5001 check send-proxy

backend i1
    server node1 192.168.40.23:5000 ssl verify none

backend i12
    mode tcp
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    server node1 192.168.40.23:5001 check send-proxy
```

I want all requests for subdomain i0. forward to i0.myserver.com and all requests for for subdomain i1. forward to i1.myserver.com with HTTP2 support. 
But in my case all requests always forward to i0.myserver.com. What is wrong with this acl rules?

Comment: There seem to be several issues, here... but you have omitted the `mode` of the front-end.  Is it tcp or http?  Also, doesn't this config show some warnings when you reload it?

Comment: tcp mode, sure. And now warning in log

Comment: Mar 13 21:21:54 template haproxy[12826]: Proxy unsecured started.
Mar 13 21:21:54 template haproxy[12826]: Proxy secured started.
Mar 13 21:21:54 template haproxy[12826]: Proxy i0 started.
Mar 13 21:21:54 template haproxy[12826]: Proxy i02 started.
Mar 13 21:21:54 template haproxy[12826]: Proxy i1 started.
Mar 13 21:21:54 template haproxy[12826]: Proxy i12 started.

Answer (score 3):

So, acl in tcp mode is not working for analyze headers. And working config is below:

```
acl rule02 ssl_fc_alpn -i h2
acl rule0 ssl_fc_sni -i i0.mydomian.com

use_backend i02 if rule02 rule0
use_backend i0 if rule0

acl rule12 ssl_fc_alpn -i h2
acl rule1 ssl_fc_sni -i i1.mydomain.com

use_backend i12 if rule12 rule1
use_backend i1 if rule1
```

Maybe it's will be useful for somebody.

Comment: acl also won't analyze path in tcp mode.  Switching to http mode provides more acl matching options if SSL is not being used - which solved the issue I was having.